# How do I best do local environment variables with CDK & SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-sam

thanks in advance for any help/guidance you could provide.

**Context**

I am currently using CDK in a project to create AWS resources (a few Lambda functions) and SAM to test locally, this works wonderfully but I'm struggling with environment variables to be used locally with my setup of CDK + SAM.

I run and test the project locally via the command

```bash
$ cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml && sam local start-api
```

Deployments are done via

```bash
$ cdk deploy testStack123 --context secretToken=123
```

The issue came when I had to include (locally) a sensitive token required for my project and I couldn't figure out how to differentiate like how you would in a project, for example, that only uses AWS SAM where you can define:

1. your local environment variables via a `env.json` file
2. and your environment variables you want to use for deployment that you'd pass in via

```bash
$ sam deploy --stack-name=testStack123 --secretToken=123
```

**What I tried?**

1. Sam's --env-vars [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html) such as:

```bash
$ sam local start-api --env-vars env.json
```

but since I'm not managing the `template.yaml` myself instead I'm relaying on CDK's `synth` command to output the CloudFormation, there is no way I can reliably reference the Lambda function names in the `env.json` to pass local environment variables via `--env-vars env.json`.

```json
// env.json example

{
  "TestLambdaFunction": {   // Will fail as its referenced in template.yaml as TestLambdaFunction67CA3BED for example
    "SECRET_TOKEN": "123"
    "ENVIRONMENT": "test"
  },
}
```

2. I tried the runtime context via `cdk.json` that the AWS team suggests for CDK envrionments but I noticed that it is also required to push the `cdk.json` file to the repo, so you always ran the risk of the dev not noticing that they’re accidentally staging and pushing sensitive tokens to the repo. However, this solution would work for both CI and local dev, but comes with the risk mentioned before.

Any advice on how to best solve this so I can make it so local environments can safely be passed via an (git)ignored filed such as `env.json` but actually work by referencing the Lambdas correctly that are emitted by the synthesised CloudFormation template cia `cdk synth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated Logical IDs like `TestLambdaFunction67CA3BED` are stable (unless you change the Construct ID or construct tree), so are generally fine to use in `env.json`  [Alternatively](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke-environment-file), you can place all the env vars under a `Parameters` key:

```json
// env.json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "TABLE_NAME": "localtable",
    "BUCKET_NAME": "testBucket",
    "STAGE": "dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Fedonev. Very helpful, but I had to take a step back and realize that the params are passed in via the CDK stack. I ended up deciding to store the sensitive token/API keys in AWS Secret manager and use `cdk.json` for non-sensitive data.